# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch on a PC?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

I want to install [Ubuntu Touch](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tablet) on PC.

They already have Preview Version Here -> *wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install* .

And some downloads here -> *cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/quantal/mwc-demo/*

---

1 - Can I do that ?

2 - And how ?

---

**Why ?** Because I want to try it, but I do not have any Nexus devices (and I don't want to buy it).

---

**YES IT'S POSSIBLE** to RUN **UBUNTU TOCH** on **PC** !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

1) **See in Action HERE** -> *www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4gXaf08GTI*

2) **Instruction HERE** - > http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/

Name of this project is **UnityNext**.

Now I try to install it but **I get error**. **Can anybody help me ?**

After command $ ./build

```
-- Found Lcov: /usr/bin/lcov  
-- Found gcovr: /usr/bin/gcovr  
-- checking for one of the modules 'hud-client-1'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:363 (message):
  None of the required 'hud-client-1' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  tests/qmluitests/qml/HudClient/CMakeLists.txt:8 (pkg_search_module)


-- checking for one of the modules 'hud-client-1'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:363 (message):
  None of the required 'hud-client-1' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  plugins/HudClient/CMakeLists.txt:5 (pkg_search_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** Не задані цілі і не знайдений make-файл.  Зупинка.
```

Comment: Have they even released a version of Ubuntu Touch yet?  That page suggests that it hasn't even been developed yet.

Comment: They have Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview -> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch

Comment: You realize you can answer your own question by referencing that wiki page?  There's a nice link at the top that says "Install" that points to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Comment: Information only about Nexus installation and not a PC. But there must be some way to run this on PC. Why? Because it was built on PC and it is Linux.

Comment: *Can I do that ?* - No. *And how ?* - You can't the OS is for ARM devices. *Information only about Nexus installation and not a PC* - And that means it's only available for ARM phones/tablets that **are** currently the Target devices for this OS, if and when an x86 port happens it's speculation. *Why? Because it was built on PC and it is Linux.* - What's that supposed to mean?.

Comment: It means next - Linux essentially made for PC, and now it runs on everything, so it's a matter of adaptation to different hardware. --- Canonical developed Ubuntu Touch on PC and using PC, so they must have Tools which allows them to Run this thing on PC for development purpose.

Comment: Just look at the name of the OS, it's Ubuntu for **Phones/Tablets/Touch** that should give you a pretty clear idea of what hardware this particular OS is meant to be running.  it's not meant to be running on a *Desktop Computer*.

Comment: UbuntuNext is meant for all devices so yes the preview should work on Ubuntu. The link you gave now has the instructions to run the ubuntu shell on the desktop. It worked fine with me.